# Of course I will to a negative sentence

Tags: negation, answers

If you say to someone
"I hope you won't stop checking in on her"
And this person answers
"Of course I will"

Does it mean "Of course I won't stop" ?

Answer (score 1):

Another interpretation is that the response is simply an elided statement.

In short, it might not, literally, mean the following:

- ✘ Of course I will stop checking in on her.

Instead, it could, literally, mean the opposite:

- ✔ Of course I will [keep checking in on her].

But regardless of what the response literally means, I can't imagine it would actually be taken to mean that the person was saying they would stop checking in on her.

---

It's similar to double negatives:

- "You don't know nothing!"

That literally means a positive:

- "You know something!"

But everybody *understands* it to mean an emphasized negative rather than a positive.

While using a double negative in this way might be considered poor grammar and a mistake in formal situations, it's still entirely understood, and it would *not* be considered a mistake by the people involved in its informal use.

Answer (score 0):

Literally it means "Of course I will stop checking on her."

Is that a surprising answer?  then probably the person misspoke and they meant "Of course I won't".  It is quite common for people to make a "mistake" in this kind of situation. We just hope that context will cover our mistakes.